# CodeIgniter 2.0 HMVC on HostGator - keeps on showing index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-2, web-hosting, codeigniter-hmvc

I have hosted my CodeIgniter site on Hostgator. I have setup the Config to the proper URL from localhost to the domain site.

I was able to load the login page / index page of my site, however when I attemp to login, it redirects me to the same page. The URL is changing, it is showing the "domain.com/website/controller/function" format.

I tried to force access a page that does not need a login but it is still the same, it redirects me to my login page.

Comment: Have you place your site in a httpd folder?

Comment: I have placed the site under a folder located on the public_html. The index page can be viewed with no problems.